# create advanced search in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm using Wordpress template, I created a page to show all news, but I wanna add a custom search form above it include the following fields

1- Start date (date picker)

2- End Date (date picker)

3- search string (text field)

after submitting a form I want to show the posts that match to the criteria

what should I do?

Comment: Hi, rewrite search.php template, add new parameters two query. View more [info](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page)

Comment: I need a clearer code